# Two past tenses in the same phrase?

Tags: verbs

I have a quick question for you. I've seen many people get their answers on this site so I hope you can help me. Is the following sentence correct?

> "I lost my wallet when I visited Mexico."

Basically I don't know if I'm allowed to use 2 verbs conjugated like this in the same sentence. To avoid this I'd use "I lost my wallet when VISITING Mexico" but the question I mentioned earlier is still bugging me. What do you think?

Comment: It isn't clear what you think may be incorrect about the usage in the example sentence. Have you been taught that it is not permitted to use two verbs in the simple past in the same sentence? If you could add to your question a short explanation of what you think is wrong with the sentence, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Can you use two finite past tense  verbs in the same sentence in your native language?

Comment: It's fine. There's no real difference in meaning between the two. They are just different ways of saying the same thing. Note that you could also say "I lost my wallet **while** visiting Mexico".

Answer (score -1):

I'm not certain why you think it's wrong to have two (or more) past-tense verbs in the same sentence.  How else you could construct simple compound sentences about things that happened in the past?

Examples:

> I *left* my home when I *was* fifteen.
>
> She *spilled* her drink, then she *dropped* her phone.
>
> I *thought* it *was* the butler who *killed* Lord Graves, but it *was* really the cook who *did* the deed.

"I lost my wallet when visiting Mexico" is fine, but it might be better to use *while* instead of *when*.  "When visiting X" is more often used to refer to the general *experience* of going to a place, and not any specific instance when you were there:

> When visiting San Diego, don't plan your trip in June as the weather is often cool and cloudy.
>
> When visiting California, be sure not to bring any fresh fruit or vegetables as these may be confiscated at the border.